# A "movie credits" like text area in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to add a list of people that looks like the credits in a movie in a layout in Android:

```
Director ................................. John Doe
Producer ............................... John Smith
Camera ................................... Jane Doe
Screenplay ............................. Jane Smith
```

I want the dots to expand according to the width of the screen (so that the position name will align to the left and the name to the right)

Is there a way to do this in a layout xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     >> android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    >>  android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:text=".........................................................................."
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    >>  android:layout_height="20dp" // set as u want....
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try this, works perfect for me.... add some more dot and will work for both Portrait and Landscape

Answer (score 0):

I would do it that way - pseudo layout.xml:

```
<frame-layout>
 <text-view text="dots"/>
 <relative-layout>
   <textview align-parent-left="true" padding-right:="5dp" text="role"/>
   <textview align-parent-right="true" padding-left:="5dp" text="name/>
 </relative-layout>
</frame-layout>
```

and this as one row in a listview

Answer (score 0):

You can make the full layout a vertically-oriented LinearLayout; each row would be a horizontally-oriented LinearLayout with three components:

A TextView with the role name, with width WRAP_CONTENT

A TextView with text "......." (lots of dots, enough for all screens), with width MATCH_PARENT and layout_weight set to 1.0

A TextView with the person's name, with width WRAP_CONTENT.